# jQuery Click Doesn't Work in FF

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-post

I have the following code which doesn't work in FireFox. Works in Chrome and IE with no error messages. The TEST alert doesn't even get fired in FF

Any suggestions? I've tried putting the JS to the top of the page but that doesn't work either.

```
<p class="hed" id="postcomment">save comments</p>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p#postcomment").click(function () {
                alert("TEST");
                $.post(
                   "putComment.asp",
                   {
                       zR: "data1",
                       zP: "data2",
                       zN: "",
                       zF1: "data3",
                       zF2: "Provider_Shortname=ALL",
                       zF3: "FinMonth=2014-02-01",
                       zF4: "",
                       zC1: $('#comment1').val(),
                       zC2: $('#comment2').val(),
                       zC3: $('#comment3').val(),
                       zC4: $('#comment4').val()
                   },
                   function (data) {
                       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                   }

                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you tried with .on("click", function() { ... } ? I've noticed that click doesn't work in safari [Maybe there are more browsers]

IT's working in my firefox btw

Comment: Do you get anything relevant in the browser console?  (F12 -> Console -> Refresh)

Comment: I would try <a> instead of <p> , some browsers don't like attaching click handlers to elements that aren't supposed to be clickable

Comment: seems to work for me in firefox 28: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKhKd/

Comment: Move the script to your `<head>` - maybe it's in an invalid block of HTML? Also, send your whole page to the W3C validator and fix up any issues.

Comment: tried everything but no luck!

Comment: How are you accessing the file in the browser?

Comment: offtopic but I agree, why would a link be a p tag? and also use `on('click'..`. Also avoid using ids for things like this - see http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

Comment: I went to make some tea, came back, refreshed and my original started working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is something else going on , here is your HTML and your jquery working in jsFiddle , even in FireFox.  The error is outside of the code that you pasted in your question

http://jsfiddle.net/DS8N4/

```
<p class="hed" id="postcomment">save comments</p>
```

Comment: Thanks - I had enough and went to make some tea. Came back and it worked. Gremlins afoot

Answer (score 0):

Since `id` is unique, try to use:

```
$("#postcomment").click(function () {
```

instead of:

```
$("p#postcomment").click(function () {
```

Also, try to use `http:` or `https:` protocol here:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That will have 0 effect.  What is the purpose or benefit of trying this?

Comment: In relation to your edit, he's using no protocol on the script include so that it uses relative protocol, meaning "whatever the page you are on is using."  This is common, every day practice.